# Discrete fractional fourier transform matrix

Tags: matrices, fourier-analysis

I am trying to write a matlab code for some calculations based on Discrete fractional fourier transform. in this article: [Optimal filtering in fractional Fourier](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Orhan_Arikan2/publication/3618543_Optimal_filtering_in_fractional_Fourier_domains/links/0912f50ee86be617c5000000.pdf). after equation (7) a notation Fa is fractional fourier transform matrix, notation a is order of transform and when a=1 the matrix will be equal to simple DFT matrix. my question is that how can i make this matrix in matlab? what is the elements of this matrix?
here: [Review of Computing Algorithms for Discrete Fractional Fourier Transform](http://maxwellsci.com/print/rjaset/v6-1911-1919.pdf) in equation (5) is a explanation about it but there is still some unknown notations for me ..
I searched too much but i didn't get the answer ... thanks in advance.